# "hear" vs. "hear about" in terms of news

Tags: word-usage

As per Cambridge Dictionary, when talking about some news, "hear" means

> to be told information about something

Cambridge Dictionary also gives these examples

> Have you **heard** the news?
>
> I hadn’t **heard about** that.

These confuse me a lot. Do they mean the same thing? Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hearing something VS Hearing about something is the same thing, just said a different way. Let's take your examples.

"Have you heard the news" VS "Have you heard about the news"

The difference would matter in other cases, though. If I 'hear the mayor,' then I am hearing him speak, or make noise. If I 'hear about the mayor,' then I am being given information about him.